# Issues trying to create the correct layout

Tags: android

Apologies in advance but I am unable to post my code because my laptop which contains Android Studio does not has access to internet. I am using a computer with LAN to post this question. I would have shown my code and ask to manipulate but as I cannot post my code I will just have to ask for a basic example and see how I can apply it to my xml file.

Basically I am trying to create my layout for my app and I want it to be displayed as so:

[image]

I am currently having issues with the layout, so want to know if I can see the basic layout for me to see and apply to my xml file

Thanks,

Comment: nice try!
( •_•)  -  ( •_•)>⌐■-■  -  (⌐■_■)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using nested layouts. Once you understood the idea of it, you will find a suitable combination yourself.

Here's an example,  that would acomplish your image:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/L_laouyout_1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Game Title"
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/iv_1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"/>



</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv_2"
    android:text="Main Text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/L_laouyout_1" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_2"
    android:text="Select another"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

so basically this?

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
        <imageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity:"right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the other answer managed to work for me but I appreciate your answer to my question